# AWS CodeDeploy Agent deployment root - old artifact, is it safe to delete?

Tags: aws-code-deploy

It looks like I have been pushing a lot of code recently and my UI instances are returning an error that hard drive memory is full. After hunting down where lots of space is being used with `sudo ncdu /` i found that my AWS codedeploy agent is taking 2.6 gigs

```
--- /opt ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2.6 GiB [##########] /codedeploy-agent
  203.2 MiB [          ] /aws
```

everything bloated is in the `deployment-root` subfolder

```
--- /opt/codedeploy-agent ------------------------------------------------------------
                         /..
    2.6 GiB [##########] /deployment-root
   17.4 MiB [          ] /vendor
  296.0 KiB [          ] /lib
  260.0 KiB [          ] /certs
   64.0 KiB [          ] /bin
   12.0 KiB [          ]  LICENSE
   12.0 KiB [          ] /state
    4.0 KiB [          ]  codedeploy_agent.gemspec
    4.0 KiB [          ]  Gemfile
    4.0 KiB [          ]  .version
```

within that folder, I can see that one of the subfolders is an artifact of a snapshot taken from last summer, June 2022 - is this safe to delete without side effects?

I cannot find any docs on AWS CodeDeploy that ever gives me a solution beyond delete and reinstall

```
$ ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Jan  4 00:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 2450 users 4096 May 25  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan  4 00:42 1442cb3e-7579-436f-8357-2a4073b9d333
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jun  7  2022 79550d19-0c84-49d6-ae0d-49f0d06a7ba7
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan  4 00:44 deployment-instructions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan  4 00:42 deployment-logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan  4 00:46 ongoing-deployment
```

Second question would be is there any way I can get codedeploy to remove its copies of the application? Its already unpacked into a different directory as part of my deployment, it's not ideal that I have 3 versions of my application sitting on the OS, 2 of them artifacts that are seemingly needless

Answer (score 2):

CodeDeploy keeps multiple revisions of the application to ensure it can perform rollback operations when needed. You can control how many revisions it keeps via the `:max_revisions:` setting of the agent configuration file, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-agent-configuration.html). This value can be set as low as 1 to only keep the most recent revision. 0 is not possible as when anything would go wrong with the deployment, it could not roll back to the earlier revision.

Regarding the folders in the `deployment-root`: the folders with GUID naming scheme refer to deployment groups. Within, you will find additional folders that refer to individual deployments. The folder with that older timestamp is probably for a deployment group that you haven't used for a while on that instance. You may remove it, if you aren't planning to do any deployments of that group anymore on that instance, but be sure to double check the details of that deployment group via the console or CLI before doing so. A backup to S3 can be sensible as well, just in case.